# ARM template integration with Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I am trying to retrieve keyVault values within my ARM template

I have enabled my keyVault for ARM template retrieval

My parameter file looks like this

```
"postleadrequesturl": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/e0f18fe9-181d-4a38-90bc-f2e0101f8f05/resourceGroups/RG-DEV-SHAREDSERVICES/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MMSG-APIManagement"
    },
    "secretName": "DEV-POSTLEADREQUEST-URL"
  }
}
```

My deploy file looks like this

```
{
  "properties": {
    "authenticationSettings": {
      "subscriptionKeyRequired": false
    },
    "subscriptionKeyParameterNames": {
      "header": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
      "query": "subscription-key"
    },
    "apiRevision": "1",
    "isCurrent": true,
    "subscriptionRequired": true,
    "displayName": "MMS.CRM.PostLeadRequest",
    "serviceUrl": "[parameters('postleadrequesturl')]",
    "path": "CRMAPI/PostLeadRequest",
    "protocols": [
      "https"
    ]
  },
  "name": "[concat(variables('ApimServiceName'), '/mms-crm-postleadrequest')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
  "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
  "dependsOn": []
},
```

The error I recieve is

Error converting value "@{keyVault=; secretName=DEV-POSTLEADREQUEST-URL}" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Entities.Deployments.KeyVaultParameterReference

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you referred to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter)?

Comment: Is that Ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, If we want to integrate Azure Key Vault in your Resource Manager template deployment, please refer to the following steps

1. Create Azure Key vault

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location
New-AzKeyVault `
  -VaultName $keyVaultName `
  -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
  -Location $location `
  -EnabledForTemplateDeployment
$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString 'hVFkk965BuUv' -AsPlainText -Force
$secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name 'ExamplePassword' -SecretValue $secretvalue
$userPrincipalName = "<Email Address of the deployment operator>"

Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy `
  -VaultName $keyVaultName `
  -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName `
  -PermissionsToSecrets set,delete,get,list
```

2. Grant access to the key vault
   The user who deploys the template must have the Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action permission for the scope of the resource group and key vault. The Owner and Contributor roles both grant this access.
   a. Create a custom role definition JSON file

   ```
    {
   "Name": "Key Vault resource manager template deployment operator",
   "IsCustom": true,
   "Description": "Lets you deploy a resource manager template with the access to the secrets in the Key Vault.",
   "Actions": [
   "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action"
   ],
   "NotActions": [],
   "DataActions": [],
   "NotDataActions": [],
   "AssignableScopes": [
   "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   ]
   }
   ```

   b. Create the new role using the JSON file:

   ```
   New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile "<PathToRoleFile>" 
   New-AzRoleAssignment `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
   -RoleDefinitionName "Key Vault resource manager template deployment operator" `
   -SignInName $userPrincipalName
   ```
3. Create ARM template

template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {

        "service_testapi068_name": {
            "defaultValue": "testapi068",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "postleadrequesturl": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
    {
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
            "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
            "name": "[parameters('service_testapi068_name')]",
            "location": "Southeast Asia",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Developer",
                "capacity": 1
            },
            "properties": {
                "publisherEmail": "v-wenxu@microsoft.com",
                "publisherName": "test",
                "notificationSenderEmail": "apimgmt-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com",
                "hostnameConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "type": "Proxy",
                        "hostName": "[concat(parameters('service_testapi068_name'), '.azure-api.net')]",
                        "negotiateClientCertificate": false,
                        "defaultSslBinding": true
                    }
                ],
                "customProperties": {
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Tls10": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Tls11": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Ssl30": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Ciphers.TripleDes168": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Backend.Protocols.Tls10": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Backend.Protocols.Tls11": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Backend.Protocols.Ssl30": "False",
                    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Protocols.Server.Http2": "False"
                },
                "virtualNetworkType": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
            "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('service_testapi068_name'), '/demo-conference-api')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('service_testapi068_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Demo Conference API",
                "apiRevision": "1",
                "description": "A sample API with information related to a technical conference.  The available resources  include *Speakers*, *Sessions* and *Topics*.  A single write operation is available to provide  feedback on a session.",
                "serviceUrl": "[parameters('postleadrequesturl')]",
                "path": "conference",
                "protocols": [
                    "http",
                    "https"
                ],
                "isCurrent": true
            }
        }

    ],
    "outputs":{

       "postleadrequesturl" :{

        "type":"String",
        "value":"[parameters('postleadrequesturl')]"

       } 
    }
}
```

paramaters.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {


        "postleadrequesturl": {
          "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/testkeyandstorage/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testkey08"
            },
            "secretName": "postleadrequesturl"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Deploy

```
$name = ""
$password = ""
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $mycreds


New-AzResourceGroupDeployment  -ResourceGroupName "testapi06"  -TemplateFile "E:\template.json" -TemplateParameterFile "E:\parameters.json"
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#grant-access-to-the-secrets

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-tutorial-use-key-vault

Comment: @david  Do you have any other concerns?